# CodeIgniter website with PostgreSql database in APPFOG

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, appfog

I am running a website in Codeigniter framework. I am using postgresql. I went through APPFOG documentation. But it is not clear to me how I configure postgres database . Where do I host the database? How do I make database updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database.php inside application/config, replace the lines,

```
<pre>
$db['default']['hostname'] = '<ur hostname>';
$db['default']['username'] = '<ur db username>';
$db['default']['password'] = '<ur db password>';
$db['default']['database'] = '<ur db name>';
</pre>
```

with

```
<pre>
$VCAP_SERVICES = getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
$VCAP_SERVICES_json = json_decode($VCAP_SERVICES, true);
$VCAP_SERVICES_postgresql_config = $VCAP_SERVICES_json["postgresql-9.1"][0]["credentials"];
$db['default']['hostname'] = $VCAP_SERVICES_postgresql_config['hostname'];
$db['default']['username'] = $VCAP_SERVICES_postgresql_config['user'];
$db['default']['password'] = $VCAP_SERVICES_postgresql_config['password'];
$db['default']['database'] = $VCAP_SERVICES_postgresql_config['name'];
</pre>
```

That would take care of database connectivity.
for making updates use af tunnel.